# Fill an Array with a String, i doknt no how it works ;( c#

Tags: c#, parsing

```
namespace For_Schleife
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Gib eine Zahl ein");
            // Eingabe Mensch
            string meineEingabe = Console.ReadLine();
            // String erstellen
            { foreach (meineEingabe)
                    Console.WriteLine(meineEingabe[1].GetType());
                Console.WriteLine($"ascii {meineEingabe[1] + 1}");

                char meineVariable = meineEingabe[1];


                if (meineVariable >= 48 & meineVariable <= 57)
                    Console.WriteLine("Ziffer");

                int meineZiffer = int.Parse(zeichen.ToString());
                meinZahlenArray[i] = meineZiffer; 
            }

            else
                Console.WriteLine("irgendetwas");

            int[] meinZahlenArray = new int[meineEingabe.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < meinZahlenArray.Length; i++)
            {

                int[] meinZahlenArray = new int[] {};
                int sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < meinZahlenArray.Length; i++)

                {
                    sum = sum + meinZahlenArray[i];


                } 
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sum); 
            

            Console.ReadKey();

        }



    }
}
```

Hello
I dont know how to become the ReadLine input

`string meineEingabe = Console.ReadLine();`

into this

`int[] meinZahlenArray = new int[] {};`

can somebody help me with hints i try to learn this iam on a early state of my learning process.

Thx in advice!

i copied this line

```
int meineZiffer = int.Parse(zeichen.ToString());
                meinZahlenArray[i] = meineZiffer; 
            }
```

from chat gpt to this Code but i have no clue what the Variable "zeichen"

means.

Comment: `int.Parse` is exactly what you want.  Or `int.TryParse`.  Read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=net-7.0), and write a proper loop.  `Parse()` will need to be called for each item in your array.

Comment: So you'll want `int meineZiffer = int.Parse(meineEingabe)` (or `int.TryParse(meineEingabe, out int meineZiffer)`)

Comment: We can roughly guess what you're trying to do, but writing your code in English would help greatly.

Comment: Thx it this was helpfull, first post on Stack overflow and first serious question.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood what you're trying to do, then this should work for you.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Gib eine Zahl ein");
    
    string meineEingabe = Console.ReadLine();
    
    if (int.TryParse(meineEingabe, out int _))
    {
        int[] meinZahlenArray = meineEingabe.Select(x => x - '0').ToArray();
        int sum = meinZahlenArray.Sum();
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
    
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear whether the input has to be only a valid number, or if you want to extract just the digits in the string.

Here's one way to approach the latter:

```
Console.WriteLine("Gib eine Zahl ein");    
String meineEingabe = Console.ReadLine();
List<int> digits = new List<int>();
foreach(Char c in meineEingabe) {
  if (Char.IsDigit(c)) {
    int i = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(c);
    digits.Add(i);
  }
}
int[] meinZahlenArray = digits.ToArray();
// ... do something with "meinZahlenArray" ...
for(int i=0; i<meinZahlenArray.Length; i++) {
  Console.WriteLine(meinZahlenArray[i]);
}
```

Sample run:

```
Gib eine Zahl ein
cat123dog456fish789lizard
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```